488 nm 30 mW 3.7 V laser: Is the driver or the diode fried at 9 V?
For a hobby project I'm doing, I accidentally gave my 488 nm 30 mW 3.7 V laser 9 V from a battery.
It appears to have died immediately.
Picture of similar laser (with housing) added for clarity. The laser was bought many years ago, but the description was similar to this:
https://www.ebay.com/itm/134968149947
or this:
https://www.amazon.com/Focusable-Cyan-Blue-Module-Positioning-12x35mm/dp/B0BRZ1W63C

Can someone tell me their best guess if it's the driver board or the diode itself that has most probably died? Isn't it the driver board's responsibility to protect the laser diode from high currents or voltages? If the board is dead, it's fairly cheap to get a new one. The laser is much more expensive.
Here are pictures of the driver board, from the front and back:


When I connect it to power now it still appears to produce a tiny bit of light, but it's very dim and it doesn't seem to be very affected by the voltage.
All I'm asking for is the educated guess by someone with some experience with this, to say if it's more probable that the driver or the diode has been damaged.

it's anybody's guess ... you provided almost zero information

You say there's a driver board. What is the actual measured voltage across the laser diode itself?

@Spehro: You want me to connect the driver board to power as in the specifications, and measure the voltage (in parallel) across the laser diode?

@jsotola: Try to help with information to get a better quality question, rather than just downvoting. Many people here are not professional electrical engineers, which is why we ask seemingly basic questions. The question was posted with all available information at hand.

What makes you think anything bought from Ebay/Aliexpress or similar scammer sites have any responsibilities at all? Is it CE marked or just yet another piece of illegal electronic junk?

@Pedery I did not downvote the question ... I made a comment that would alert you to think about what you wrote ... your response should have been what information am I missing? ... You also asked a technical question about an unknown driver board ... you do not have to be an engineer to know that you did not provide any information about the driver board

@jsotola I've provided all the information I have, and more. Also, I'm asking for a qualified opinion, not an absolute answer. Because if I'm going to replace either part here, I'd like to know what part is most likely broken, and start with that, rather than wasting money on new parts that will never be used.

if the driver board failed, it may have destroyed the laser diode ... replace both components ... if that's not an option, then replace the driver board first ... there is a smaller chance that a bad laser diode will damage a new driver board ... there is a greater chance that a bad driver board will destroy a new laser diode

Those < $1 laser diode pointer things typically don't have a 'driver' with feedback or 'specifications' like a fancy Thorlabs laser diode.
The laser diode chip isn't even packaged, the raw die is bonded to a thin brass plate and the other side of the die is wire-bonded to tiny PCB. The 'driver' is a  series resistor of a few 10's of Ω. They emit light from the edge of the die, unlike LEDs.

So, yes, it's now become e-waste. R.I.P. wee laser die.

Thanks for the answer. If you read my question, this is not a <$1 laser diode. It's a $34 cyan laser diode with a separable collimating lens and a small PCB about 10mm * 20mm with a number of components on it, and a lot of white goo that I assume is for cooling. This laser and PCB is probably not top notch quality, but I believe it's not bottom shelf either. So my original question about whether the driver board has protected the diode or if it's "normal" that it gets fried with 8-9 V from a used 9 V battery still stands.

The driver board is similar to this:
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS53j3IrfSWlYie5D47-HRqV9GJHFMLvlI6Rg&s
I can provide an actual picture next time I'm in the location of the laser, if necessary.

I've added a picture of the driver board in the main question.

@Pedery I don't see any active parts on that side of the board, though the inductor suggests a switching supply of some kind. Maybe there's a chip on the other side?

I've added a picture of the other side of the driver too. Tried to scoop away some of the goop that is probably thermal paste.
